# Typings modules cannot be found

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify

I want to use external modules only in my current project so I installed `typings` with npm. I downloaded `d3` and have a problem with it.

In `Application.ts` file I have:

```
import * as d3 from "d3"
```

Sublime Text 3 underlines `"d3"` as not found. I can compile it though with tsconfig as below:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outDir": "built"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/Application.ts",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

However when I'm trying to use browserify then it tells me that it `Cannot find module 'd3' from 'path_to_project\built'`.

Ideally I would like to improve my gulpfile task to handle it.

```
gulp.task("default", function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: ".",
        debug: true,
        entries: ["src/Application.ts"],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}    
    })
    .plugin(tsify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("js"));
});
```

What am I doing wrong? My `typings.json` is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "registry:npm/d3#3.0.0+20160211003958"
  }
}
```

**Update**

I downloaded d3 via `npm i d3` and gulp works now. However is there any possibility to choose a directory where browserify looks for modules? It seems that the modules must be under `node_modules` directory.